# Why is the iostream not working properly here?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, iostream

Here is my main:

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList<int> L1; 
    LinkedList<int> L2;
    int val,k;

    cout<<"\nPlease enter int values to add to the list L1 (-1 to stop):\n";
    cin>>val;
    while(val != -1)
    {
        L1.InsertBeg(val);
        cin>>val;
    }
    L1.PrintList();

    cout << "\nPlease enter int values to add to the list L2 (-1 to stop):\n";
    cin >> k;
    while (k != -1)
    {
        L1.InsertBeg(k);
        cin >> k;
    }
    L1.PrintList();

    return 0;
}
```

and here is the output:

> Please enter int values to add to the list L1 (-1 to stop): 1 2 3 -1 
>   [ 3 ]--->[ 2 ]--->[ 1 ]--->NULL 
>   Please enter int values to add to the list L2 (-1 to stop): 4 5 6 -1 
>   [ 6 ]--->[ 5 ]--->[ 4 ]--->[ 3 ]--->[ 2 ]--->[ 1 ]--->NULL

But it's not the expected, the expected one is:

> Please enter int values to add to the list L1 (-1 to stop): 1 2 3 -1
>   [ 3 ]--->[ 2 ]--->[ 1 ]--->NULL
>   Please enter int values to add to the list L2 (-1 to stop): 4 5 6 -1
>   [ 6 ]--->[ 5 ]--->[ 4 ]--->NULL

so what is wrong here, why does this happen?

Comment: Please make your [mre] complete.

Comment: I think you insert second list to L1 in `while(k != -1)` and print L1, too.

Comment: You're not entering anything into `L2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write

```
cout << "\nPlease enter int values to add to the list L2 (-1 to stop):\n";
```

but you still add values into L1

```
while (k != -1)
    {
        L1.InsertBeg(k);
        cin >> k;
    }
```

you should change this lines as L2